# Servlet Controller with duplicate Statement

Tags: java, oop, web-applications

I tend to have this statement

```
STKUser authenticatedUser = (STKUser) request.getSession().getAttribute("STKUserSession");
```

in every method of my Classes.  `authenticatedUser` is used for authorization checks/ logic flow. Is this OK or should I be coding this class differently???  Also are there any recommended books that could help improve my coding for Java Classes like the one below, which are used in web applicatons?  Most of my Classes looked like the one below.

```
public class TD0301AssignmentForm extends Form {
  private boolean notifyApprover = false;
  boolean employeeChange = false;

  public TD0301AssignmentForm(TD0301AssignmentDAO dao) {
    this.dao = dao;
  }


  private TD0301Assignment unlockAssignment(HttpServletRequest request) {
    STKUser authenticatedUser = (STKUser) request.getSession().getAttribute("STKUserSession");
    TD0301Assignment tdas = new TD0301Assignment();
    notifyApprover = true;
    boolean unlock = false;

    try {
        // get the original data
        tdas = dao.retreive(request.getParameter("calc_num"), request.getParameter("calc_rev"), request.getParameter("calc_dept"), authenticatedUser);

        if ("3".equals(tdas.getForm_approve_state()) && authenticatedUser.getBadge().equals(tdas.getOriginator())) {
            tdas.setForm_approve_state("1");
            notifyApprover = true;
            unlock = true;
        }

     }


public TD0301Assignment updateAssignment(HttpServletRequest request) {
    STKUser authenticatedUser = (STKUser) request.getSession().getAttribute("STKUserSession");
    .... 
    if (authenticatedUser.getBadge().equals(tdas.getOriginator())) {
        //do something
}
```

## EDIT

The `TD0301AssignmentForm` Class is accessed using these two Classes.

### Servlet

```
TD0301AssignmentDAO dao = new TD0301AssignmentDAO();
TD0301AssignmentForm form = new TD0301AssignmentForm(dao);
TD0301Assignment obj = new TD0301Assignment();

String pkString = "calc_num=" + request.getParameter("calc_num") + "&calc_rev=" + request.getParameter("calc_rev") + "&calc_dept="
        + request.getParameter("calc_dept");

modelMap.put("dbTable", dbTable);
modelMap.put("action", request.getRequestURL());
modelMap.put("reportTitle", "CommitmentReport");

// I think this is the Application Controller Strategy
actionMap.put(null, new ListAction(modelMap, form, "WEB-INF/views/genericList_v.jsp", "WEB-INF/views/genericList_v.jsp"));
actionMap.put("list", new ListAction(modelMap, form, "WEB-INF/views/genericList_v.jsp", "WEB-INF/views/genericList_v.jsp"));
actionMap.put("view", new ViewAction(modelMap, form, obj, "WEB-INF/views/genericView_v.jsp", "WEB-INF/views/genericView_v.jsp"));
actionMap.put("delete", new DeleteAction(modelMap, form, obj, "WEB-INF/views/genericDeleteConfirm_v.jsp", "WEB-INF/views/genericView_v.jsp"));
actionMap.put("sqlConfirmDelete", new DeleteConfirmAction(form, request.getRequestURL() + "?message=Deletion was successful!", request.getRequestURL()
        + "?method=view&" + pkString));
actionMap.put("edit", new EditAction(modelMap, form, obj, "WEB-INF/views/genericEdit_v.jsp", "WEB-INF/views/genericView_v.jsp"));
actionMap.put("sqlUpdate", new UpdateAction(modelMap, form, obj, request.getRequestURL() + "?message=Update was successful!", "WEB-INF/views/genericEdit_v.jsp"));
actionMap.put("new", new NewAction(modelMap, form, "WEB-INF/views/genericAdd_v.jsp"));
actionMap.put("sqlInsert", new InsertAction(modelMap, form, obj, request.getRequestURL() + "?message=Insert was successful!", "WEB-INF/views/genericAdd_v.jsp"));

String op = request.getParameter("method");
ControllerAction action = (ControllerAction) actionMap.get(op);

if (action != null) {
    action.service(request, response);
} else {
    String url = "WEB-INF/views/errorMessage_v.jsp";
    String errMessage = "Operation '" + op + "' not a valid for in '" + request.getServletPath() + "' !!";
    request.setAttribute("message", errMessage);
    request.getRequestDispatcher(url).forward(request, response);
}
```

---

```
public class EditAction implements ControllerAction {

private Form form;
private Object obj;
private String xPage;
private String yPage;
private HashMap modelMap;

public EditAction(HashMap modelMap, Form form, Object obj, String yPage, String xPage) {
    this.form = form;
    this.obj = obj;
    this.xPage = xPage;
    this.yPage = yPage;
    this.modelMap = modelMap;
}

public void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    obj = form.edit(request);

    Iterator it = modelMap.entrySet().iterator(); 
    while (it.hasNext()) { 
        Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)it.next(); 
        request.setAttribute(pairs.getKey().toString(), pairs.getValue());       
    }

    request.setAttribute("obj", obj);
    request.setAttribute("form", form);

    if (form.isSucces()) {
        RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher(yPage);
        view.forward(request, response);
    }
    else {
        RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher(xPage);
        view.forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I do use a servlet filter to 'authenticate' the user.  Not sure how or what you mean to make my class more cohesive.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were not using a filter. Is that `TD0301AssignmentForm` a servlet ?

Comment: Sort of... I edited my question to include two more classes. I realize my style is UNORTHODOX!! But I am forced to use at work Sun Java Server 6.1 with Java 1.4 and a ton of Confguration Management procedures.  So I can not utilize some of the great practices and frame works available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you find yourself retrieving the same value all the time, you'd probably at *least* want to abstract it into a method in a base class:

```
public class BaseForm extends WhateverYouHave {
    public STKUser getUser(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return request.getSession().getAttribute("STKUserSession");
    }
    ...
}

...

public class AnotherServlet extends BaseForm {
    public TD0301Assignment updateAssignment(HttpServletRequest request) {
        if (getUser(request).equals(tdas.getOriginator())) {
        ...
```

Another, potentially cleaner option depending on your dispatch/instantiation/etc. mechanism would be to inject the value into your forms (if they're not singletons, unclear):

```
public class AnotherServlet extends BaseForm {
    public AnotherServlet(STKUser user) {
        this.user = user;
        ...
    }

    public TD0301Assignment updateAssignment(HttpServletRequest request) {
        if (user.equals(tdas.getOriginator())) {
        ...
```

Or provide it as an argument to form methods (if they are):

```
public TD0301Assignment updateAssignment(STKUser user, HttpServletRequest request) {
    if (user.equals(tdas.getOriginator())) {
        ...
```

It's unfortunate your forms are tied directly to the servlet spec; it's more pleasant to do as much development as possible without that requirement.

Comment: Dave, thanks for understand my problem and question. I do have a base class for Forms. I could inject, but tried your first suggestion first. Eclipse marked that I needed to add the argument request. So I have STKUser authenticatedUser = getUser(request); I will try to inject. BTW, authenticatedUser (your user) is a bean with a bunch of setters and getters.

Comment: cool, I injected the value from the calling Servlet.  This seems to be exactly what I was after.  I am always paranoid about thread safety and hope this causes no issues in regards to that.  
   public TD0301AssignmentForm(TD0301AssignmentDAO dao, STKUser authenticatedUser) { this.dao = dao; this.authenticatedUser = authenticatedUser; }

Comment: My forms are HTML.  Are there any good sites/book that can teach me how to untie my forms from the servlet spec?  Pretend that it is the year 2001 since that is about the time frame when my server and version of Java were last updated.  It has to work with this outdated platform.

Comment: @jeff I can't speak to its thread safety, since I don't know how it's used. If there's a new form object created per-request, or it's a `ThreadLocal`, it *should* be fine, but obviously I'm guessing.

Comment: @jeff It's the class itself that's tied to the servlet spec (passing around `HttpServletXxx` instances). There are a number of ways around that, but it may not be worth it to start changing unless you have functional tests in place to validate new behavior.

Comment: @jeff It *looks* like the forms are created per-request, although the servlet is missing a bit that would help answer that. It also looks like the action map is created per-request, which is weird, unless it was to avoid creating some sort of factory.

Comment: Dave thanks again.  You are right, I could use a factory for the action map but for me it was easier to hard code.  I have a Servlet per form, instead of one central servlet.  Please look for more of my questions :) - I am learning a lot from you!